# How to create table in yii with use createcommand or other?

Tags: php, database, yii

how to create a table using createCommand in Yii? 
I've followed the instructions in the http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand but I am still confused. Can you give an example of creating a table using createCommand in yii. 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've named your database connection string **db** (in `protected/config/main.php`) as follows,

```
'components'=>array(
    'db'=>array(
    ),
),
```

you should be able to create a table using the following command:

```
$sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20))";
$sqlCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlQuery);
$sqlCommand->execute();
```

You should also be able to replace the first line with any SQL statement and execute it successfully.  If you want to query for data, you will need to use queryRow, queryColumn, or queryScalar (as defined in the documentation).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and sucess..

> Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CREATE TABLE {$nama_data}(id serial, {$list_field}, x text,y text,wkt text, the_geom geometry,PRIMARY KEY(id));")->query();